# Visual Studio 2019 hangs when opening a solution with a dual targeted dotnet core and net framework project converted by hand

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

A developer migrated a csproj file to the newer csproj syntax. The top of the csproj file follows:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{4CF6CFA6-13B2-426E-913B-A42BF6642A69}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Other developers were no longer able to open the two solution files containing this project. Visual studio would begin opening the solution, but the progress bar would hang when it got to this converted project. It should be noted that many other projects had been migrated without this issue.

A blank solution was created and the hanging project was added to this blank solution. This opened without a hang.

Any ideas on what could be done to allow this project to not hang. I suppose a new project could be created as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the hang by creating a new project GUID and replacing the old project GUID in the csproj and sln files. This allowed the solution to open. I used the Visual Studio GUID tool available in the Visual Studio Tools main menu to create the GUID in registry format.